# Postgresql/psql rebuild dumped table fails

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I have a table that was created with pgAdmin4 (12.0) on Windows 10. I used the following to dump the data to a file.

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe" --data-only 
--file="C:\\Users\\ciris\\DOCUMENTS\\programming\\pg_out\\test.sql" 
--host="localhost" --port="5432" --username="postgres" --password --verbose
--format=p --no-owner --no-privileges --table="pc.ebd_sel_pt" "ebird_work"
```

The dump file is ~2GB. I want to take the dump file, test.sql, and recreate the table on a linux Postgresql db. I created the db in psql (v10) on linux with:

```
CREATE TABLE ebc.eb_sel (
global_unique_identifier VARCHAR,
common_name VARCHAR,              
scientific_name VARCHAR,
observation_count VARCHAR, 
state_province VARCHAR,
county VARCHAR,
locality VARCHAR,
longitude NUMERIC(8,5),        
latitude NUMERIC(8,5),       
observation_date DATE,        
time_observations_started VARCHAR,
first_name VARCHAR,
last_name VARCHAR,       
protocol_type VARCHAR,
all_species_reported INTEGER,
sampling_event_identifier VARCHAR,
obs_time TIMESTAMP,
point INTEGER);
```

To import the data to the linux version of the table that was created in Windows, I used the following:

```
\COPY ebc.eb_sel 
FROM '/d/data/linux/pgsql/data/dat1/test.sql' 
WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I get an error in psql that says,

```
2020-08-08 07:33:12.005 EDT [2297] ERROR:  missing data for column "common_name"
2020-08-08 07:33:12.005 EDT [2297] CONTEXT:  COPY eb_sel, line 2: "-- PostgreSQL database dump"
2020-08-08 07:33:12.005 EDT [2297] STATEMENT:  COPY  ebc.eb_sel FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
ERROR:  missing data for column "common_name"
CONTEXT:  COPY eb_sel, line 2: "-- PostgreSQL database dump"
```

What is causing this error?

EDIT- after the suggestion from @GiuseppeSchembri that my pg_dump statement was wrong, I rewrote part of it. Now it is:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe" --data-only 
--file="C:\\Users\\ciris\\DOCUMENTS\\programming\\pg_out\\test.sql" 
--host="localhost" --port="5432" --username="postgres" --password 
--verbose --format=p --no-owner --no-privileges --dbname="ebird_work" 
--table="pc.ebd_sel_pt"
```

More specifically, I changed `--table="pc.ebd_sel_pt" "ebird_work"` to `--dbname="ebird_work" --table="pc.ebd_sel_pt."` As I replied directly to @GiuseppeSchembri below, the db is "ebird_work", the schema is "pc", and the table is "ebd_sel_pt".

I made a new dump file with that command. I tried the same \COPY statement and I get the same error. I dropped the table I made and remade it with all of the column names in all capitals (I think the original table was all in caps).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dump the tables `pc.ebd_sel_pt` and `ebird_work` you should write
`--table=pc.ebd_sel_pt` `--table=ebird_work`.
Your pattern `"pc.ebd_sel_pt" "ebird_work"`seems suspiciously wrong, see PostgGresql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html#PG-DUMP-EXAMPLES) on `pg_dump` for details.

Edited for a second attempt:

The simplest thing to try would be

`psql dbname < dumpfile` on the Linux machine ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-LARGE)).

Or if you want to use `COPY`.

I wonder if using `pg_dump` with `--data-only` create a file suitable to be imported with `COPY`.

Could you try to use `COPY TO`(you have to access `psql` on the server)? (see the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html) for further details).

Something like this

```sql
COPY table_name
TO 'absolute_path/filename'
WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Make sure to grant all permissions to the folder in absolute_path (beeing in windows I don't know if this is necessary).

But if the table is really large you may want to use a [compressed dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-LARGE).

`pg_dump dbname | gzip > filename.gz`.

If you have some problem importing the dump from a `postgres` v12 to a `postgres` v10 you can create a cluster with v12 on the Linux machine.

Comment: I see. ebird_work is the db that holds the pc.ebd schema. The table is named ebd_sel_pt. I had to figure out how to write the \COPY statement by searching on the web. I misunderstood where I wrote "--table=pc.ebd_sel_pt  ebird_work". I thought the page/source I looked to get that idea had left the schema at the end for some reason. I think your point has helped me try to rewrite the pg_dump statement, but it's still not correct. I have to try another version.

Comment: @JohnPolo I edited the answer if you wish to try with `COPY TO` instead of `pg_dump`

Comment: Hi @GiuseppeSchembri. I tried what you suggested. Still didn't work. I realized the dump statement was creating an .sql file and the \COPY that I was trying to restore with was written for a csv, so dropped the csv clause in the \COPY. I took a subset of the table by creating a new table with a SELECT that had a LIMIT 100 clause. I could open up the dump file then to see inside. I couldn't find anything wrong with the "common_name" column. But then I noticed that some of the other columns were not aligned correctly. Thus there seems to be a problem with a column somewhere. In 8000000+ rows...

Comment: ... I don't know how to check the other columns for data that is misaligned. It's weird that pgAdmin4 never complained about this problem. I don't know if there is a "-" or something else that is causing this problem. I created another dump file and tried to read it back in on the Windows side of thing with the psql server in the cmd that works with the Version 12 db from which the table was dumped to begin with. There are 2 errors. Either it's the same error about "common_name" column or "ERROR: extra data after last expected column". I'm shelving this for now. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: I revisited this problem and found an answer after experimenting with a smaller DB and some of the information you supplied. I wrote my findings into a new answer. Since you put effort into helping me and I used that info, I though maybe you would revise your answer to include the basic point of my answer (drop "--data-only" and create new DB from scratch) and then with your updated answer reflecting what I wrote, I could accept your revised answer, so that you get credit.

Answer (score 0):

The dump statement needs to be changed to:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe" 
  --file="C:\Users\ciris\DOCUMENTS\programming\pg_out\all.sql" 
  --host="localhost" --port="5432" --username="postgres" --password --verbose 
  --format=p --no-owner --no-privileges --dbname="ebird_work" --table="p_loc.ebird_sel_spt"
```

The problem apparently stemmed from the "--data-only" option that I included in the original statement. I dropped it from the `pg_dump` statement that worked. Here is what appears at the start of an SQL file that is output from a `pg_dump` command that included "--data-only":

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 12.3
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 12.3

-- Started on 2020-12-15 13:41:57

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- TOC entry 3730 (class 0 OID 31041)
-- Dependencies: 226
-- Data for Name: ebird_sel_spt; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: pc; Owner: -
--

[Data begins here...]
```

In a `pg_dump` command without the "--data-only" option, the output includes this:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 12.3
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 12.3

-- Started on 2020-12-15 13:42:54

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;

--
-- TOC entry 226 (class 1259 OID 31041)
-- Name: ebird_sel_spt; Type: TABLE; Schema: pc; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE pc.ebird_sel_spt (
    "GLOBAL_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER" text,
    "COMMON_NAME" text,
    "SCIENTIFIC_NAME" text,
    "OBSERVATION_COUNT" text,
    "STATE_PROVINCE" text,
    "COUNTY" text,
    "LOCALITY" text,
    "LONGITUDE" double precision,
    "LATITUDE" double precision,
    "OBSERVATION_DATE" text,
    "TIME_OBSERVATIONS_STARTED" text,
    "FIRST_NAME" text,
    "LAST_NAME" text,
    "PROTOCOL_TYPE" text,
    "ALL_SPECIES_REPORTED" integer,
    "SAMPLING_EVENT_IDENTIFIER" text,
    "OBS_TIME" timestamp with time zone,
    point integer,
    geom public.geometry(Point,26910),
    pt_lon double precision,
    pt_lat double precision
);


--
-- TOC entry 3730 (class 0 OID 31041)
-- Dependencies: 226
-- Data for Name: ebird_sel_spt; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: pc; Owner: -
--
[Data...]
```

The `CREATE TABLE` code in the `pg_dump` without "--data-only" creates the new table from scratch, so I don't need to create the table before using

```
psql new_ebddb < all.sql
```

to recreate the table in a new DB.